# Retrieve Id from ResponseUri in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I want to retrieve id from ResponseUri.

I have following URL

http://site5.way2sms.com/Main.action;jsessionid=77C20044847CD2C97BA89217A4D040A8.w803?id=77C20044847CD2C97BA89217A4D040A8.w803

I want to retrieve id from above string. How can I do this?

Comment: BTW: You shouldn't post true session ids + URL when you post here... otherwise, you might become the victim of session hijacking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string iduri = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(res.ResponseUri.Query).Get("id");
```

use this

Answer (score 4):

```
Uri uUri = new Uri("http://site5.way2sms.com/Main.action;jsessionid=77C20044847CD2C97BA89217A4D040A8.w803?id=77C20044847CD2C97BA89217A4D040A8.w803");
string strId = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uUri.Query).Get("id");
```